# ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth

Всем привет, я сделал программу для блютуз сервера, но при ее запуске появляется ошибка

```
ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "sdp_uuid128_create" referenced by "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/bluetooth/_bluetooth.cpython-311.so"...
```

Работаю в termux на андроиде, pybluez установлен, что делать? Гуглил, но ничего не откопал.